# AppDelegate runtime error related to Storyboard XCode 9.2

Tags: xcode, storyboard, runtime-error, lldb

To brief you:

1) I recently updated XCode to version 9.2, and am now using iOS 11.2 (up from iOS 8.3).

2) I have a screenshot of the error although I don't believe it will tell you much (then again, I could be wrong.)
[LLDB runtime error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Bnr.png)

3) I have added CorePlot to my project via GitHub download, then added a branch release via a Podfile.  If this has anything to do with the issue, then I'll go into more detail about it.

**reading off the specifics of the errors under Thread 1

4) `62 UIMainApplication` has error in line 61

```
0x18c0095c4 <+236>: mov    x0, x20
```

5) `0 __cxa_begin_catch` has error

```
libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_begin_catch:
    ->  0x181c23ed0 <+0>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-0x20]!`
```

I've run my app on my iPhone a couple times after updating and I've never had a runtime error upon startup (or at all for that matter.)

However, I started having this problem after I decided to move some of the `UIView` object positions (labels, a 2 buttons, a custom graph view) to re-center them for a larger iPhone device (I haven't used AutoLayout just yet, so I had to do this manually.)  Furthermore, before I moved the views, left and up autoresizing constraints were already part of the objects.

So that's where I'm at. I've never run into this problem and don't know how to even ask the right, technically-sound questions to get close to a solution.

ALSO: My Storyboard file is just `Main.storyboard` and that (Along with all the other file names) have not changed when updating Xcode or adding the CorePlot branch release podfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger is stopping here because it hit an Exception breakpoint that you must have set at some point in time.  You set these in the Breakpoints navigator by selecting "Exception Breakpoint" and choosing ObjC or C++, and throw or catch.

It is stopping on the exception catch.  Did it also stop on the exception throw?  If not, you may have only added a catch breakpoint and you might want to add an Exception breakpoint on the throw as well.  The point of throw is usually more instructive than the catch point.

The other thing to note is that by default Xcode hides the frames in the backtrace that are not in your code (except for the transition frames into and out of your code.)  But to figure out who is throwing the exception you want to see these frames.  You can do that by clicking on the left-most of the gadgets in the filter window at the bottom of the Breakpoint Navigator.

Comment: Oh, what an error I've made!...forgetting to check the breakpoint navigator!  Although I appreciate your explanation, didn't know that much about the situation at hand (and no, it was only on the catch, not a throw at all.)